# Can we give separate permission for VSTS work items and Tasks?

Tags: azure-devops, backlog

Can we give separate permission for VSTS (Azure DevOps) work items and Tasks? it will help some easier to manage kanban board.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

No. Work item permissions are assigned at the area path level. If someone has access to create or modify work items under an area path, they can create or modify **any type** of work item. There are no permissions on a type by type basis.

Comment: very strange thing ... ui ux of microsoft products in all last 20 years is bad and access to sth need 10 extra clicks